# Convert a vector to data frame with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector as stated below:

```
("#99" "Hershey" "$6.7 B" "7%" "$4.7 B" "$562 M" "Consumer Packaged Goods"
 "#100" "Costco" "$6.7 B" "14%" "$117.3 B"  "-"  "Retail")
```

For simplicity i have mentioned only few elements out of 700 elements.

I want to convert it to data frame as below:

```
S.NO  Brand Brandval Change Revenue  Cost   Industry
99  Hershey $6.7 B    7%     $4.7 B  $562M   Consumer Packaged goods
100 Costco  $6.7B     14%    $117.3B  -     Retail
```

I was trying as.data.frame but it gives me results in one single column while I want to split it into 7 columns as explained above.
Please help.

Comment: as.datafram(df) here df is ur  data

Comment: if I apply as.data.frame on the vector, its giving me one single column.

Comment: `as.data.frame(matrix(vec,ncol =7,byrow = T))`, `vec` being your vector.

Comment: Why is this thread getting downvoted ?

Comment: Because the sample data you provided is not reproducible and you show no effort of trying to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this: split your vector according to a vector of repeated `1:7`, then apply `cbind.data.frame`. Eventually, add column names

```
x=c("#99", "Hershey", "$6.7 B", "7%", "$4.7 B", "$562 M", "Consumer Packaged Goods", "#100", "Costco", "$6.7 B", "14%", "$117.3 B",  "-",  "Retail")
res <- cbind.data.frame(split(x, rep(1:7, times=length(x)/7)), stringsAsFactors=F)
names(res) <- c("S.NO", "Brand", "Brandval", "Change", "Revenue", "Cost", "Industry")
str(res)
#### 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  7 variables:
####   $ S.NO    : chr  "#99" "#100"
####   $ Brand   : chr  "Hershey" "Costco"
#### ...
```

You can choose the option `StringAsFactors` so that you get either character or factor columns

Comment: the solution provided by @mtoto in above comments also work though. Thanks.