# How to import a CSV file in R with misaligned rows and columns?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rows

I am trying to import modelling results into R. The model spits out 68 entries per time step. However, the formatting of the .txt file (white space delimited) is off. The first 5 entries are placed on the first line and from there on a new line starts for every 1-6 entries. 
Importing this as CSV therefore results in a dataframe with 5 columns and 16 rows, instead of a single row with 68 columns.

Defining the column headers and using the fill option results in a data frame with 68 columns, of which everything after the 5th is filled with NA.

```
col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(68)))
```

I feel like there must be an option to sort this time series with a fixed number of entries per row. What am I missing?

Data looks like this:

```
        2013           1           1  0.0000000E+00  0.7999797    
  0.0000000E+00  0.7976342      0.7976342       4.600000      0.0000000E+00
   5.400000      0.9950000      0.0000000E+00   969.0231      0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00
   134.2833      0.0000000E+00  7.5260596E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2500000       453.5565       397.1019     -1.1351937E-04  1.1351937E-04
   37.85871       134.2833     -8.6918109E-05  0.3779435      0.8803711    
  0.0000000E+00 -1.1351937E-04  1.1351937E-04  -180.3156      1.0273202E-03
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.6856970      0.1142827    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000       1.000000      0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  -165.6710      0.0000000E+00   5.400000       77.18394    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  1.1351937E-04  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import is as a csv. Read it into a single string and then parse it:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
tx <- read_file('        2013           1           1  0.0000000E+00  0.7999797    
  0.0000000E+00  0.7976342      0.7976342       4.600000      0.0000000E+00
   5.400000      0.9950000      0.0000000E+00   969.0231      0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00
   134.2833      0.0000000E+00  7.5260596E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2500000       453.5565       397.1019     -1.1351937E-04  1.1351937E-04
   37.85871       134.2833     -8.6918109E-05  0.3779435      0.8803711    
  0.0000000E+00 -1.1351937E-04  1.1351937E-04  -180.3156      1.0273202E-03
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.6856970      0.1142827    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000       1.000000      0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  -165.6710      0.0000000E+00   5.400000       77.18394    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00  1.1351937E-04  0.0000000E+00
  0.0000000E+00') %>%  # Just put the filename here instead
  trimws()%>%
  strsplit('\\s+') %>%
  unlist()%>%
  as.numeric()

# tx 
# [1]  2.013000e+03  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  7.999797e-01  0.000000e+00  7.976342e-01  7.976342e-01  4.600000e+00
# [10]  0.000000e+00  5.400000e+00  9.950000e-01  0.000000e+00  9.690231e+02  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.342833e+02  0.000000e+00
# [19]  7.526060e-03  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  2.500000e-01  4.535565e+02  3.971019e+02 -1.135194e-04  1.135194e-04  3.785871e+01
# [28]  1.342833e+02 -8.691811e-05  3.779435e-01  8.803711e-01  0.000000e+00 -1.135194e-04  1.135194e-04 -1.803156e+02  1.027320e-03
# [37]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  6.856970e-01  1.142827e-01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
# [46]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.656710e+02  0.000000e+00  5.400000e+00  7.718394e+01  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [55]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
# [64]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.135194e-04  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks! Reading it as a string and then splitting it works wonderous. In parsed it into a data frame and it looks like the way it is intended to look. 

For other people following these steps: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655452/convert-a-vector-to-data-frame-with-multiple-columns?rq=1)