# How to make vector elements become new columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
temp <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   B=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   C=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

and I also have a vector as follows:

```
variables <- c("D", "E", "F")
```

what I want to do is add the elements in `variables` to be new columns in the df `temp`.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655452/convert-a-vector-to-data-frame-with-multiple-columns) example because I thought the question was somewhat similar, but by running `as.data.frame(matrix(variables,ncol = length(temp), byrow = T))` like in the example, and then cbinding to temp, it assigned variable names V1, V2 and V3 to the column headers, and the first observations were D, E, and F.

What Im hoping for is something like this:

```
> temp
   A  B  C D  E  F
1  1  1  1 Na Na Na
2  2  2  2 Na Na Na
3  3  3  3 Na Na Na
4  4  4  4 Na Na Na
5  5  5  5 Na Na Na
```

I feel like it should be something easy but Im just completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add them directly as columns:

```
temp[variables] = NA
temp
#   A B C  D  E  F
# 1 1 1 1 NA NA NA
# 2 2 2 2 NA NA NA
# 3 3 3 3 NA NA NA
# 4 4 4 4 NA NA NA
# 5 5 5 5 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, (variables) := NA]
```

---

Or with `cbind`

```
cbind(temp,  setNames(rep(list(NA), length(variables)), variables))
```